# Package aws lambda artificat

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

1. pip3 install -t dependencies -r requirements.txt
2. (cd dependencies; zip ../aws_lambda_artifact.zip -r .)
3. zip aws_lambda_artifact.zip -u main.py

These are the 3 commands I used to create my lambda artifact, package my application and dependencies. What if my application contains more files? Is there a way to package all files to the artifact?

```
-db
  -config.py
  ..
-routers
  -user_router.py
  ..
 
main.py
```

Comment: I’m not sure how this is “deploying” anything…?

Comment: That zip file is actually just a regular zip file, read up https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip if this command must be run from CLI, otherwise just use your regular file manager to handle it.

Comment: Did you try simply adding the other files to the ZIP file, possibly in a subdirectory such as resources/ or assets/?